# How to plot several lists for different values of independent variable in a same graph?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

How could I plot parameters Br and Dr for several values of t0 starting from -3 to 0 with step size 1 for the following ode? I was able to plot t0=-3 and want to plot other lists of parameter set {Br,Dr } derived from different points of t0 in the same graph.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
t0 = -3; b = 2;

ode1 = y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t];

ode2 = x'[t] == -Cos[x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/(2*
   y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1)));

ode3 = v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + Sin[x[t]]/(2*y[t]^2);

bc = {x[t0] == 0, y[t0] == Br, v[t0] == Log[Dr]};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, bc}, {x, y, v}, {t, t0,0}, {c, Br, Dr}]
 data = Table[FindRoot[{(y[c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, v[c, Br, Dr][0] /. sol}, {{Br,1}, {Dr, 1}}], {c, 0.3, 2.2, .05}];
Br = Br /. data; Dr = Dr /. data;

ListLinePlot[Thread[{Dr, ArrayResample[Br, Length@Dr]}],Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Br", ""}, {"Dr", ""}}]
```

Comment: Do you mean to plot several `data` in one `Plot`?

Comment: I meant another set of Br and Dr data from the table for another values of t0 and show them altogether in a same graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Do` loop as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
b = 2;

ode1 = y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t];

ode2 = x'[
    t] == -Cos[
      x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/(2*
       y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1)));

ode3 = v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + 
    Sin[x[t]]/(2*y[t]^2);

bc = {x[t0] == 0, y[t0] == Br, v[t0] == Log[Dr]};


Do[t0 = -3 + i/2; 
 sols[i] = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, bc}, {x, y, v}, {t, t0, 0}, {c,
     Br, Dr}]; 
 dat[i] = 
  Table[{Br, Dr} /. 
     FindRoot[{(y[c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sols[i], 
       v[c, Br, Dr][0] /. sols[i]}, {{Br, 1}, {Dr, 1}}] // Quiet, {c, 
    0.3, 2.2, .05}]; 
 lst[i] = 
  Thread[{dat[i][[All, 2]], 
    ArrayResample[dat[i][[All, 1]], Length@dat[i]]}], {i, 0, 5, 1}]
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[Table[lst[i], {i, 0, 5, 1}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Br", ""}, {"Dr", ""}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t0 =", -3. + i/2}], {i, 0, 5, 1}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Trounev. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Dibbo123 Question about solution mark is very advanced. Better to start new post. Maybe somebody has a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.