# How could I deal with and mark point of singularity or non-existance?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

ode1 = y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t];
ode2 = x'[t] == -Cos[x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/(2*y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1)));
 ode3 = v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + 
Sin[x[t]]/(2*y[t]^2);
bc = {x[t0] == 0, y[t0] == Br, v[t0] == Log[Dr]};
Do[tstar = -3 + i/2;
sols[i] = ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, bc}, {x, y, v}, {t, tstar, 0}, {b, c, Br,Dr}];
data[i] = Table[{Br, Dr} /. FindRoot[{(y[2, c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sols[i], v[2, c, Br, Dr][0] /. sols[i]}, {{Br, 1}, {Dr, 1}}] // Quiet, {c, 0.3, 2.2,.01}];
lst[i] = Thread[{data[i][[All, 2]], data[i][[All, 1]]}], {i, 0, 4, 1}]
ListLinePlot[Table[lst[i], {i, 0, 4, 1}], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Br", ""}, {"Dr", ""}}, PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"tstar =", -3. + i/2}], {i, 0, 4, 1}]]
```

For the above problem,I want to run two more loops for the parameter Br =1 to 3 with any step size and Dr =20 to 40 with any step size and plot them for several points of t0 like above. Also, for 'FindRoot' ,we will now determine parameters b and c rather than Br and Dr. We will have certaintly many points of Br and Dr where solutions will not exist(singularity) and I need to mark those points where I don't have solutions(mark some rectangle or circle or something else or could fill in some boxes if solution exist vs leave them blank if not exist).

Comment: ... and your question is? Perhaps you could show us what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Actually, I do not have engouh experice in mathematica. I tried but my codes did not work due to singularity or stiffness.

Comment: @MarcoB Actually, there is similar question and answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273694/how-to-plot-several-lists-for-different-values-of-independent-variable-in-a-same/273741#273741 . This post mostly about how mark solution in a case of when `FindRoot` successfully compute roots.

Answer (score 1):

Dibbo:  Best if you break it up into small parts and test them separately.  First just need to get the DE working.  You have three bugs:  You define b=2 but specify it as a parameter in `ParametricNDSolve`, you don't define t_0, and you need to `Join` the system with the boundary conditions if not specifying them explicitly in the `ParametricNDSolve` construct.

(1)  First get the DE working with a specific value of $t_0=-3$ and $c=2$:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
b = 2;
ode1 = y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t];
ode2 = x'[
    t] == -Cos[
      x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/(2*
       y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1)));
ode3 = v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + 
    Sin[x[t]]/(2*y[t]^2);

i = 0;
t0 = -3 + i/2;
theC = 2.0
bc = {x[t0] == 0, y[t0] == Br, v[t0] == Log[Dr]};
theSols = {x, y, v} /. 
  ParametricNDSolve[
   Join[{ode1, ode2, ode3}, bc], {x, y, v}, {t, t0, 0}, {c, Br, Dr}]
xF = theSols[[1]];
yF = theSols[[2]];
vF = theSols[[3]];
p1 = Plot[{xF[theC, 0.5, 1][t], yF[theC, 0.5, 1][t], 
   vF[theC, 0.5, 1][t]}, {t, -3, 0}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{Style["c: ", 12, Bold, Black], Style[theC, 12, Bold, Black]}]]
```

The way I've coded it, the three solutions are given by xf[c,Br,Dr][t], yF[c,Br,Dr][t] and vF[c,Br,Dr][t].  In the above code I plot the three with c=2, Br=0.5, and Dr=1 in the range of t from -3 to 0:

[image]

Spend some time working with this code and test it with various values of "theC" variable.  Then start thinking about expanding it further as you wish.